# Using unexported functions/types from stdlib in Go

Tags: go, package, private-methods

**Disclaimer:** yes I know that this is not "supposed to be done" and "use interface composition and delegation" and "the authors of the language know better". However, I am confronted with a choice of either copy-pasting from the standard library and creating my own packages, or doing what I am asking. So please do not reply with "What you want to do is wrong, you are a bad dev and you should feel bad."

So, in Go we have the `http` stdlib package. This package has a number of functions for dealing with HTTP Range headers and responses (parsers, a struct for "offset+size" and so forth). For various reasons I want to use something that is very similar to `ServeContent` but works a bit differently (long story short - the amount of plumbing needed to do the `ReaderAt` gymnastics is suboptimal for what I want to accomplish) so I want to parse the HTTP `Range` header myself, using the utility functions/structs from the `http` stdlib package and then deal with them manually. Basically, I want a changed version of `ServeContent` :-)

Is there a way for me to "reopen" the `http` stdlib package to use it's unexported identifiers? ABI is not a concern for me as the source is mine, the program gets compiled from scratch every time etc. etc. and it does not need binary compatibility with older/other Go versions. I.e. I am able to ensure that the build is going to be done on a specific Go version and there are tests to check that an unexported identifier disappeared. So...

If there is a package called `foo` in the Go standard library, but it only exposes a `MagicMegamethod` that does the thing I do not need, and uses `usefulFunc` and `usefulStruct` that I want to get access to, is there a way for me to get access to those identifiers? Either by reopening the package, or using some other way... that does not involve copy-pasting dozens of lines from stdlib without tests etc.

Comment: What do you have against "copy-pasting dozens of lines"? You are about to circumvent one of Go's basic principles, and you're afraid to duplicate a few hundred lines of code? Believe me, duplicating is easier (and you get portability and backward / forward compatibility for free...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist ([rather gruesome](http://www.alangpierce.com/blog/2016/03/17/adventures-in-go-accessing-unexported-functions/)) ways of accessing unexported symbols, but it requires nontrivial amounts of tricky code, so there's unlikely to be a net win.

Since you've outruled the "don't do this" direction, it seems that the answer is either NO or use the methods described in the post I linked to ([and this repo](https://github.com/alangpierce/go-forceexport)).

FWIW I'd personally just copy the code I need from the standard library and tweak it to my needs. This would likely take less time than the time it took you to write this SO question :-)

Comment: Yeah you are right - the way is indeed too gruesome to be applied in the wild. Or rather, it might work for some time on some version but having other people be confrontend with it's use would be too bad of a gift